# Unable to export data to PostgreSQL from Oracle

Tags: postgresql, etl, talend

I have to extract data from Oracle tables and copy them to PostgreSQL. I am able to map both the input and output files. On running the connector component I get the proper row fetching graphical image, but when I go to the table there is no such data.

This one is for PostgreSQl to PostgreSQL:

[image: This one is for PostgreSQl to PostgreSQL]

TRACE_DEBUG result
[After trace debug this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJKXC.png)

Comment: The question is not clear. Maybe add a picture with your problem to the question.

Comment: Please find the image in the link of the question

Comment: With this picture and the description your problem still isn't clear.

Comment: As you can see there are no errors in the window still I am unable to export the data to the destination database.

Comment: Everything works out fine, 4 rows are being transmitted, you don't use any transactions... looks fine to me. Have you tried a *Debug Run*? Are you sure you looked into the right table?

Comment: I tried, Its showing the table data being uploaded on the graphical window. At the end it uploads all the records but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Seems to me that either you look into an old, cached version of your data or the db prunes the data for some reason. Try re-checking all parameters and reloading the database viewer tool.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you trying to read and write on the same table in Input and Output ? (this could be a problem).
- What kind of action are you using in the output , insert, update, insert or update ?
- Did you check if there is a lock on your output table ?

Comment: No two different tables are there. I tried both "Insert" and "Insert or Update" options and there are no locks.

Comment: okay, did you check if your user has the 'Insert' rights on the given table ? You could also try to check 'die on error' in the output component, see if it shows something.

Comment: Yes logged in as Admin. I have access to all the rights. I also tried 'die on error' still no luck. I am not getting any error that is the hurdle.

Comment: Could you try to set the "commit every" option (in Advanced Settings of tPostgresSQLOutput) to 1 (default is 10000), to see if this could be related to the commit mode ?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the settings on your database connection, you may need to turn on auto commit or add an explicit commit component at the end of the Flow.

How is the output component configured ?

- operation type : insert?
- is it doing a lookup?
- is the table name correct ?
- did you check the error code global value for the component After it finishes ?

Comment: Yes I am performing an Insert operation. The table name is correct too. I've also tried to set Auto commit  to ON. Error code=0 I think its fine.

Comment: Did you check the error code global value for the component After it finishes ?

Comment: Yes it indicates operation completed successfully.

Comment: The same set of global values will indicate the number of rows inserted . What is the variable name and number ?

Comment: I have uploaded the trace_debug image link. have a look at it

Comment: Trace link doesn't help at all, unfortunately. It shows what flowed into the final component. It doesn't show what happened in the output component .